# retrive info via websocket

Tags: websocket, node-red

I have a device that responds me (via HTTP post) with information useful for connecting to it's web socket for give some measures.
I have a template in .NET code. It is possible to rebuild same logic using NODE-Red nodes?

```
String Payload="resources=1&1=/rw/iosystem/signals/;state";
HttpConnection.Connect("http://127.0.0.1");
HttpResponse = HttpConnection.Post("/subscription", Payload);
InitialEventsXml = HttpResponse.GetBody();
WebSocketUrl = HttpResponseGetHeader("Location");
WebSocketConnection.addHeader(HttpResponseGetCookies());   


WebSocketConnection.Connect(WebSocketUrl,WebSocketSubProtocol='robapi2_subscription'); 
    EventsXml = WebSocketConnection.Receive();
```

Answer (score 1):

No, because you cannot dynamically set the Websockets URL for the Websocket nodes

Comment: .....some alternative or workaround using template node and browser node?

Comment: No, the best you probably do is write a custom node.